# Negative value of likelihood function in Kalman filter

Tags: optimization, likelihood, kalman-filter

I use kalman filter algorithm, where I minimize the value of likelihood function. But after some iteration I got negative value of likelihood function. Is that a problem?

Comment: (A) why minimize rather than maximize?  (B) are you looking at the likelihood or the log-likelihood or the negative of the log-likelihood?

Comment: @Henry maybe I do not understand it correctly. I am using Kalman filter on this website: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/arbitrage-free-nelson-siegel-model-with-r-code/. It follows the algorithm used in this article https://www.frbsf.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/wp07-20bk.pdf page 13-15. So to answer your question I am looking at the log-likelihood function. I return -loglike so I am not really sure if it means the negative of the log-likelihood. Can you please explain?

Comment: If you are using the log-likelihood then it is quite possible to get positive or negative values when taking the logarithm of a positive likelihood.  Similarly if your optimization function only deals with minima so you minimize the negative of the log-likelihood rather than maximizing the likelihood or the log-likelihood, it is quite possible to get negative or positive values for the negative of the log-likelihood when taking the negative of the logarithm of a positive likelihood.

Comment: In any case, likelihood is only meaningful up to proportionality, so the log-likelihood and negative of the log-likelihood are only meaningful up to an additive constant, which may be a positive or negative as you need, so the signs of the log-likelihood or negative of the log-likelihood are not something to worry about.

Comment: @Henry thank you